# In Objective-C, are there any specific rules for declaring global variables in .m files?

Tags: objective-c, global-variables, declaration

By reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7958939/cannot-declare-variable-inside-interface-or-protocol), It looks like certain rules should be considered when declaring global variables.

So I tried declaring global variables in the .m file. However, the code sense seems not happy to do this for me. For example, say I already have 2 lines in the .m file:

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize abc, xyz;

Now I want to add "BOOL isChecked;".

If I type this below "@synthesize" (or just between @implementation and @synthesize), the code sense actually suggests me to input "bool" (lower case) as I am typing "BOOL". If I type "BOOL" above "@implementation", it would suggest "BOOL" successfully.

Surely, the global variable is part of this class which means it should be inside the implementation. I am not sure why it doesn't like to let us do this.

This makes me feel that Objective-C doesn't like us to declare global variables below @synthesize. But my question is WHY? What I feel is that there may be a reason or Apple made a bug here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Surely, the global variable is part of this class which means it should be inside the implementation. I am not sure why it doesn't like to let us do this.

Global variables *aren't* part of a class. Sure, you can put them inside an `@implementation` block, but they're really not a part of the class -- they're global -- so they don't really belong there.

Objective-C doesn't have class variables like Java or other languages do. You can fake them with global variables and class methods that access those variables, but at the end of the day, they're global, not specific to a class.

Answer (score 0):

What the IDE's code sense help suggests is not an absolute indication of what the Objective C language "likes".  Putting a global variable either outside or inside a class implementation generates equivalent compiled results from the Xcode Objective C compiler, and with no warnings.

However it might be considered better code style to put these declarations outside of the class implementation, as all global variables actually have global scope, not class scope.

In addition, you might want to assign an initial value to your global variables, instead of making any assumptions in your code of what that might be.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C does not have class variables. You declare a C global variable. This is how I do it:

Declare a static C variable. In your case:

```
static BOOL isChecked = NO;
```

Notice that I have initialized it. Notice that it is declared static, which restricts its visibility to the .m file it is declared in.

If you want a global object such as an array, you will need to initialize it:

```
static NSArray *myArray;

@implementation MyClass

+ (void)initialize {
    if (self == [MyClass class]) {
        myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: ... ];
    }
}

@end
```

Notice the *if (self == [MyClass class])* check. *+initialize* will be called one or more times. Once when *MyClass* is used for the first time (e.g. call to *+alloc*). Possibly again when any subclass of *MyClass* is used for the first time. Hence the check to see if you are actually initializing MyClass, or a subclass of it.

And finally, if you want to access this variable outside of the code that it is declared in, create an accessor:

```
+ (BOOL)isChecked {
    return isChecked;
}
```

Don't expose the global C variable by removing the *static* modifier. It makes it harder to debug, refactor or re-implement (what if *isChecked* suddenly depends on other state, how do you change this if it is directly used all over the place in other code?)